# Populate combox with dataset headers using C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, dataset

I am trying to make a search/filter function for a `DataSet` I have displayed in a `DataGridView`.

I want to populate a `ComboBox` with the headers from my `DataSet` so they can select what column to search.

I have tried this:

```
var headers = aSH_ORDER_DBDataSet1.ASH_PROD_ORDERS.Columns;

foreach (var header in headers)
{
    comboBox1.Text = header.ToString();
}
```

But I am obviously doing something wrong as it only adds the last column name to the `ComboBox`, which is strange.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that at each iteration step you overwrite the [Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which

> Gets or sets the text associated with this control.

So you end up having only the last item in your `ComboBox`

You need to add the strings to the [Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(header.ToString());
```

becase it is

> representing the collection of the items contained in this ComboBox.

Comment: @JamesMorrish no problem. :)  Glad I could help